# Issue with creating a promise on `key_entered` event for geofire

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I want to create a function, returns promise, which uses geofire library to query firebase based on lat lng and radius. How to create dependency on geofire call back function for 'key_entered' event, to complete its call back function execution, and then resolve promise.

```
function geofireQuery(lat, lng, rad){
  const result = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const geofireRef = new GeoFire(admin.database().ref('geofire'));
    geofireRef.query({
      center: [lat, lng],
      radius: rad //kilometers
    }).on('key_entered', (key, location, distance) => {
        result.push(key);
    });
    resolve(result);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `resolve` needs to be inside the `on('key_entered'`:

```
function geofireQuery(lat, lng, rad){
  const result = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const geofireRef = new GeoFire(admin.database().ref('geofire'));
    geofireRef.query({
      center: [lat, lng],
      radius: rad //kilometers
    }).on('key_entered', (key, location, distance) => {
        result.push(key);
        resolve(result);
    });
  });
}
```

This ensures the promise gets resolved when the first key comes in. If you want to resole the promise when all keys have come in, add a listener for [`on('ready'`](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#geoqueryoneventtype-callback), which fires when all the initial keys have come in.